# Syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER in Ruby JSON String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a Feature test using RSpec and Capybara with my Rails 4 app which includes a Transloadit upload.

I'm trying to follow them [gem](https://github.com/transloadit/rails-sdk) documentation to stub out the call to Transloadit, but I'm getting an error.  In the documentation, it says to put the JSON values, like this:

```
def example_json
  "{ ... JSON content from a real POST ... }"
end
```

However, when I put my sample JSON:

```
def example_json
    "{
      "ok": "ASSEMBLY_COMPLETED",
      "http_code": 200,
      "message": "The assembly was successfully completed.",
      "assembly_id": "ac9daa70e7bc11e58cfdb3c26b8231f5",
      "parent_id": null,
      "account_id": "067d87c0a16f11e59fa6a78f6ec29a04",
      "template_id": "5494d070a37811e5adb70b0aa0a9dfa6",
      "instance": "mhairi.transloadit.com",
      "assembly_url": "http://api2.mairi.transloadit.com/assemblies/ac9daa70e7bc11e58cfdb3c26b8231f5",
      "assembly_ssl_url": "https://mairi.transloadit.com/assemblies/ac9daa70e7bc11e58cfdb3c26b8231f5",
      "bytes_received": 721,
      "bytes_expected": 721,
      "upload_duration": 0.037,
      "client_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586",
      "client_ip": "81.227.172.81",
      "client_referer": "http://localhost:3000/lessons/hello/edit",
      "start_date": "2016/03/11 19:08:44 GMT",
      "is_infinite": false,
      "has_dupe_jobs": false,
      "execution_start": "2016/03/11 19:08:44 GMT",
      "execution_duration": 0.012,
      "notify_start": null,
      "notify_url": null,
      "notify_status": null,
      "notify_response_code": null,
      "notify_duration": null,
      "last_job_completed": null,
      "fields": {},
      "running_jobs": [],
      "bytes_usage": 0,
      "executing_jobs": [],
      "started_jobs": [],
      "parent_assembly_status": null,
      "params": "{\"template_id\":\"187d070a37811e5adb70b0aa0a9dfa6\",\"auth\":{\"key\":\"****\",\"expires\":\"2016/03/11 19:38:25+00:00\"}}",
      "template": "{\"steps\":{\"safe\":{\"use\":\":original\",\"robot\":\"/file/virusscan\",\"error_on_decline\":true},\"image_thumbs\":{\"use\":\"safe\",\"robot\":\"/image/resize\",\"result\":true,\"format\":\"png\",\"width\":200,\"height\":200,\"resize_strategy\":\"crop\"},\"optimized\":{\"use\":\"image_thumbs\",\"robot\":\"/image/optimize\",\"result\":true},\"files\":{\"use\":\"safe\",\"robot\":\"/file/filter\",\"declines\":[[\"${file.meta.duration}\",\">\",\"1800\"]],\"error_on_decline\":true},\"encode\":{\"use\":\"files\",\"robot\":\"/video/encode\",\"ffmpeg_stack\":\"v2.2.3\",\"preset\":\"ipad\"},\"export\":{\"use\":[\"encode\",\"optimized\"],\"robot\":\"/s3/store\",\"key\":\"****\",\"secret\":\"****\",\"bucket\":\"foobar\"}}}",
      "uploads": [],
      "results": {}
    }"
  end
```

I get the error `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER`.

I checked the JSON [here](http://sonlint.com) and it looks valid, so I'm unsure what's going wrong.

Comment: You're using " in a "-quoted string. Perhaps you could enclose the string in '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all the double quotes inside the JSON string with single quotes.

Your double quote string literals cannot contain double quotes without escaping. `"John said, \"Well ain't that something.\""`

You can use single quotes inside double quotes with no escaping needed.

**Single Quotes** (Not Valid JSON)

```
def example_json
  "{
    'ok': 'ASSEMBLY_COMPLETED',
    'http_code': 200
  }"
end
```

Another StackOverflow member has pointed out that single quotes are not valid in JSON objects. To have valid JSON you can use escaped double quotes.

**Escaped Double Quotes**

```
def example_json
  "{
    \"ok\": \"ASSEMBLY_COMPLETED\",
    \"http_code\": 200
  }"
end
```

Since that would be rather painful to type backslashes the whole way through the JSON object, wrap the valid JSON in a multi-line **heredoc**.

**Heredoc**

```
def example_json
  <<-JSON
  {
    "ok": "ASSEMBLY_COMPLETED",
    "http_code": 200
  }
  JSON
end
```

http://rubyquicktips.com/post/4438542511/heredoc-and-indent

Comment: JSON strings and values are required to be wrapped in double quotes -http://www.json.org - so your example isn't technically valid

Comment: @TomWalpole Added note about invalid JSON and provided two alternative methods with valid JSON including heredoc. Thanks for pointing that out!